# Laravel - how to confirm destroy method in a popup?

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, popup

I have multiple forms which delete data from my Laravel application and I was wondering. How can I best make this more user friendly by having to confirm the deletion of these items?

**This is the code that I currently use to remove records in a table (without confirmation).**

```
<td class="col">
    <form action="{{ route('campaigns.destroy', $campaign->id) }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('DELETE')
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right" title="Verwijderen">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
        </button>
    </form>
</td>
```

**This is what my destroy method looks like**

```
public function destroy(Campaign $campaign): RedirectResponse
{
    $campaign->delete();

    return redirect()->route('campaigns.index');
}
```

**What I have tried**

I have tried to use javascripts native `confirm()` function. But this turns out really ugly so that's why it is not an option for me.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=delete-confirmation-modal

Comment: Confirmation alert Before Delete record with jQuery AJAX
  https://makitweb.com/confirmation-alert-before-delete-record-with-jquery-ajax/

Comment: @Collin Can I also do this without it being async with AJAX?

Comment: @Kheteshkumawat Can I also do this without it being async with AJAX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [sweetalert2](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2)

```
<td class="col">
   <button type="button" data-url="{{ route('campaigns.destroy', $campaign->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right" title="Verwijderen">
        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
   </button> 
</td>
```

JS

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-danger', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    var token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
    swal({
            title: "Are you sure!",
            type: "error",
            confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes!",
            showCancelButton: true,
        },
        function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: {_token: token, _method: 'DELETE'},
                success: function (data) {
                     //
                }         
            });
    });
});
```